# A video streaming API with in-video quizzes

Tags: video, javascript, web-development, html, api

I'm working on a MOOC (Massive Open Online Course) platform and we need videos for lectures and in-video quizzes. I need an API which enables the video maker to pause the video and have quizzes in between, much like coursera does.

For example, the video is streaming, and at 1:21, there is a quiz. The video screen itself should have the quiz and as soon as the user submits the quiz (multiple choice/subjective), the video should resume.

Following are the requirements along with this:

- The video player needs to be HTML5 based (I seriously doubt flash would work on all platforms)
- The video plugin should be responsive and smartphone-compatible.

While looking for video plugins, I had come across video.js. It seems nice, but I couldn't find the in-video quiz functionality I need in it. Any recommendation?

Comment: I think your requirement of having it HTML5 based is the biggest obstacle here. It would probably be easier to find, or to make, if you allowed pure desktop solutions. But using some JavaScript, it would be possible to make this (I'm not a fan of JS though, so don't count on me making it)